# Bluetooth doesn't work at system boot Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: bluetooth

When I boot up the system, the Bluetooth shows as being off. Tried turning it on and it doesn't anything.

Only way to make it work is unplug the bluetooth adapter and plug it back in.

Any suggestions on how to get it working at boot?

Answer (score 0):

Something is not installed by default for Bluetooth. In Ubuntu Software Center search for: Bluetooth Support.

This package provides all of the different plugins supported by the Bluez Bluetooth stack.

Comment: Bluetooth Support returned zero items

Comment: The package's name is simply "bluetooth". Did installing it solve your problem?